# Mingw package with top util

Tags: mingw

Is there MinGW package with top util? I searched from pacakge list and don't found it.

I found package procps for Cygwin - http://cygwin.com/packages/procps/ with top util. But I can't find similar package for MinGW.

Thanks.

Comment: Top util - I mean util, that show system usage by each process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Cygwin utilities work like the Linux ones, but they only work on
>   Cygwin processes. For Windows processes, you need to use Windows
>   utilities, such as the ones from Sysinternals. PsKill can kill
>   processes by name.

### [unix.stackexchange.com/a/19428](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19428)

Comment: Thank you. Actually I tried Cygwin top, and it works only for cygwin processes. Sysinternals tools are really awesome.